# How to reshape a table having multiple records for the same id into a table with one record per id without losing information?

Tags: sql, pandas, sas

Basically, I want to transform [this(Initial)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwcvO.png) into [this(Final)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IXfs.png). In other words, I want to

- "squash" the initial table so that it will have only one record per id
- "dilate" the initial table so that I won't lose any information: create a different column for every possible combination of source and column from the initial table (create c1_A, c1_B, ...).

I can work with the initial table as a csv in Python (maybe Pandas) and manually hardcode the mapping between the [Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwcvO.png) and the [Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IXfs.png) table. However, I don't find this solution elegant at all and I'm much more interested in a sql / sas solution. Is there any way of doing that?

Edit: I what to change

```
+----+--------+------+-----+------+
| ID | source |  c1  | c2  |  c3  |
+----+--------+------+-----+------+
|  1 | A      |  432 |  56 |    1 |
|  1 | B      |   53 |   3 |   73 |
|  1 | C      |    7 | 342 |   83 |
|  1 | D      |  543 |  43 |   73 |
|  2 | A      |    8 | 882 |   39 |
|  2 | B      |    5 |  54 |   46 |
|  2 | C      |    8 |   3 | 2226 |
|  2 | D      |   87 |   2 |   45 |
|  3 | A      |   93 | 143 |   45 |
|  3 | B      | 1023 |  72 |    8 |
|  3 | C      |    3 |   3 |  704 |
|  4 | A      |    2 |   5 |    0 |
|  4 | B      |   78 | 888 |    2 |
|  4 | C      |   87 |  23 |   34 |
|  4 | D      |  112 |   7 |  712 |
+----+--------+------+-----+------+
```

into

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| ID | c1_A | c1_B | c1_C | c1_D | c2_A | c2_B | c2_C | c2_D | c3_A | c3_B | c3_C | c3_D |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |  432 |   53 |    7 |  543 |   56 |    3 |  342 |   43 |    1 |   73 |   83 |   73 |
|  2 |    8 |    5 |    8 |   87 |  882 |   54 |    3 |    2 |   39 |   46 | 2226 |   45 |
|  3 |   93 | 1023 |    3 |      |  143 |   72 |    3 |      |   45 |    8 |  704 |      |
|  4 |    2 |   78 |   87 |  112 |    5 |  888 |   23 |    7 |    0 |    2 |   34 |  712 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: What have you tried? In SAS it looks like like you just want a trivial double proc transpose.  Post your data as text instead of photographs to get a programmed solution.

Comment: I did not know about the double proc transpose, I think it may solve my question immediately. Also, how can format my data so that it is displayed nicely as a table?

Comment: Here are instructions on how to post your data as a data step: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-a-data-step-version-of-your-data-AKA-generate/ta-p/258712

Comment: Tom is correct, you want a transpose and use the ID option to get both variables in your new Variable name. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-wide-to-long-using-proc-transpose/

Comment: It is almost comically often how the idea to move a value from a data column into a column name becomes a later headache.  If you stick with the original data shape there are procedures such as `REPORT` and `TABULATE` that very effective in presenting the data in the transposed form.  If you pursue the transpose path you pivot from a categorical data shape to an 'across' data shape and trade the power of `where` `class` and `by` for a potential purgatory of `array`, `vname` and `scan`

Comment: @Richard, definitely agree. Storing the data in a long format is usually 10x more efficient for further calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abandon hope ... ?

```
data want;
input 
  ID   source $  c1    c2     c3;datalines;
   1   A         432    56      1  
   1   B          53     3     73  
   1   C           7   342     83  
   1   D         543    43     73  
   2   A           8   882     39  
   2   B           5    54     46  
   2   C           8     3   2226  
   2   D          87     2     45  
   3   A          93   143     45  
   3   B        1023    72      8  
   3   C           3     3    704  
   4   A           2     5      0  
   4   B          78   888      2  
   4   C          87    23     34  
   4   D         112     7    712  
;

* one to grow you oh data;
proc transpose data=want out=stage1;
  by id source;
  var c1-c3;
run;

* and one to shrink;
proc transpose data=stage1 out=want(drop=_name_) delim=_;
  by id;
  id _name_ source;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I think that double proc transpose suggested by Tom (in the comments) solves my problem, too.